# init with parameter in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am in a situation where I have to create an `init` with a parameter.

```
- (id) initWithSomeParameter:(id)parameter;
```

Normal `init` should not be called. So, I have two choices to accomplish this. I can actually throw an exception when some one calls the `init` or return `nil`.

Which should be done and why?

Comment: I would use a designated initializer (as per JRG-Developer) but if a parameter is absolutely required (and `nil` is not valid) then return `nil` from your designated initializer. `nil` is a valid response to an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a **designated initializer**, which all other `init` methods call.

In your example, the designated initializer would perhaps be

```
- (id)initWithSomeParameter:(id)something;
```

If another programmer calls `-(id)init` instead of the designated initializer, you might do something like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithSomeParameter:nil];
}
```

If you absolutely **must** have a value provided for `someParameter`, you can raise an exception if you choose to, but this practice varies with how important getting a value is on initialization of the instance object.

Here's Apple's input also on using a designated initializer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say without knowing more about your use case. However, Perhaps you are being too strict with your API.

`UIKit` itself is full of classes that need some data to operate, but don't require it on init.  Take `UIImageView` for example.  You may think "an *image* view requires an *image* to do anything, therefore I should require an *image* on init!".  However, this snippet here is a perfectly valid use case:

```
UIImageView *foo = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
foo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar"];
```

Here we make an image view, and assign the image itself in a second step.  So instead throw exceptions when you try to use your object in ways that require data to be present if that data isn't present.

---

Also, your designated initializer is usually the one that typically takes the most arguments, and the rest call that one. Something kind of like this may be more what you want.

```
- (id)init {
    // call this class's designated initializer
    return [self initWithSomething:nil];
}

// this class's designated initializer
- (id)initWithSomething:(NSString*)something {
    self = [super init]; // call superclass's designated initializer
    if (self) {
        // this class's setup code goes here, saving any arguments
        somethingInstanceVar = something;
    }
    return self;
}

// some other method.
- (NSString*)doSomething {
  if (somethingInstanceVar) {
    // all is well, do stuff
    return somethingInstanceVar;
  } else {
    // never got a "something" raise an exception
    [NSException raise:@"Missing data" format:@"Something is required!"];
  }
}
```